# Numpy subtracting rows of a 2D array from another 2D array without for loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I know that if we try to subtract a row vector **v**(1,3072) from a 2D array **A**(5000,3072) if A and v does have same number of column v is broadcasted, but subtracting stack of row vectors **V** (each row of **V** having to be subtracted to the whole of **A**) cannot be done.
I can't figure out how to subtract V's rows one by one from A without using a `for` loop.

```
 def compute_distances_one_loop(V):
        num_test = V.shape[0]
        num_train = A.shape[0]
        dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
        for i in range(num_test):   
            initial=np.sqrt(np.square(A-V[i,:]))
            dists[i,:]=initial.sum(axis=1)
        return dists
```

Heres the semi-vectorized form of this problem, how do I get rid of that for loop?

For example

```
matrix_e=np.ones((3,3))*6
matrix_f=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

how do I get the matrix_g of shape (6,3) without using a for loop?

```
matrix_g=np.array([[5,4,3],[5,4,3],[5,4,3],[2,1,0],[2,1,0],[2,1,0]])
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, V is of shape (k, 3072) and you want to substract V from all corresponding "slices" of A ? If so, perhaps create an array of the same shape as A by repeatedly concatenating instances of V ?

Comment: Exactly, v is (500,3072). No need to create a array of the same size as A because when subtracting a row vector from A, that row is broadcasted to the A's number of rows which the above code does which has a for loop inside

Comment: Will the dimension of `A` be an even multiple of the corresponding dimension of `v`?

Comment: Indeed, but I understood you wanted to extend the broadcasting principle to an array of several rows. If I'm mistaken, please provide an example.

Comment: yes thats what I wanted, sorry about my poor english

Comment: yes, A is (5000,3072) and V is (500,3072)

Comment: Your code and description is confusing.  The code has `self` and `X` (or `self.Xtrain`), while else where you talk  about `A` and `V`.   A [mcve] might help, with (3,4),(9,4) etc shaped arrays.  Just a guess, reshaping `A` to (10,500,3072)` might help?

Comment: Ok I think you want to substract EACH row of V in turn to the whole of A. I think it's possible with broadcasting by adding a third dimension to both matrices. I'll work on the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can make a big array (of the same size as A) by concatenating occurrences of V:

```
height_A, height_V = A.shape[0], V.shape[0]
occurrences, remainder = divmod(height_A, height_V)
mask = [V for i in range(occurrences)] + [V[:remainder]]
big_V = np.concatenate(mask)
```

Now you can safely do A - big_V !

(I separated steps to make it clearer, but you can easily combine them into a single statement

```
big_V = np.concatenate([V for i in range(A.shape[0]//V.shape[0])] + [V[:A.shape[0]%V.shape[0]]])
```

)

Edit - I better understand what you need now: subtract EACH row of V from the whole of A. It's possible by adding a third dimension to both arrays like in the following picture, where A2 - V2 is represented by the array of green panes[image], to make use of broadcasting.

```
A2 = np.expand_dims(A, axis = 0)  # from shape (5000, 3072) to (1, 5000, 3072)
V2 = np.expand_dims(V, axis = 1)  # from shape (500, 3072) to (500, 1, 3072)
print (A2 - V2)   # broadcasting makes the resulting shape (500, 5000, 3072)
```

Example, with:

```
A = np.ones((3,3))*6
V = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

print(A2 - V2)
# array([[[5., 4., 3.],
#         [5., 4., 3.],
#          [5., 4., 3.]],
#
#        [[2., 1., 0.],
#         [2., 1., 0.],
#         [2., 1., 0.]]])
```

And you can calculate the array of distances between rows of A and V:

```
D = np.sqrt(np.square(A2 - V2).sum(axis = 2))

# array([[7.07106781, 7.07106781, 7.07106781],
#        [2.23606798, 2.23606798, 2.23606798]])
```

Comment: Hmmm after re-reading your code, I think I misunderstood your intent. Please add an example (with small arrays of course) of what you want to do.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your efforts sir, I wanted to subtract every row of V (2,3) for A(3,3) one by one with broadcasting every row of V and subtracting them. A=[[6,6,6],[6,6,6],[6,6,6]] and V=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] resulting in a matrix c=[[5,4,3],[5,4,3],[5,4,3],[2,1,0],[2,1,0],[2,1,0]]

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Can I also get the link of this image?

Comment: You'll welcome; as for the image, just download it :) Btw, for the distance calculation in your question, don't you need to do the sum BEFORE the square root?

Comment: Yes.. It took me a while to see that, thanks a lot again!

Comment: So, after using my 2nd code to do the subtraction, I guess you only need to do `np.sqrt(np.square(A2 - V2).sum(axis = 2))`.